# How do I tell which Edition and Version my SSAS Instance is running?

Tags: ssas, dmv, tabular-model

In SQL Server on the database engine, you can run a SQL query like this to get the server's version info like Edition and Version, and Update Level, etc.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

What is the MDX equivalent for querying an SSAS (Tabular or Multidimensional) instance? Are there SSAS DMVs that can get me this answer?

I browsed the [Books Online page for SSAS DMVs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820), but I didn't notice any DMVs that could help me. DISCOVER_INSTANCES didn't seem to have the info.

Let's assume that SQL Server Database Engine is not installed on this same server as the SSAS instance, so I cannot check this by querying the database engine.

In my case, this is for a SQL 2012 Tabular instance, but would like to know how to query Multidimensional instance too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is :

using SSMS -- connect to instance --> reports -> standard reports --> General

[image]

[image]

There are other ways as well - [How to find Analysis Services Server Version ?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlman/2008/03/25/how-to-find-analysis-services-server-version/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via PowerShell for a list of servers:

```
$list = 'server1','server2'

$loadInfo = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
if($ssas){Clear-Variable -Name ssas -scope local}
$list | %{
         $target = $_
         $server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
         try{
             $server.connect($target)
             $ssas +=  @($server | Select-Object @{l="ServerName";e={$target}}, Name, Edition, Version, ServerMode,DefaultCompatibilityLevel,CreatedTimestamp,LastSchemaUpdate)
            }
         catch{ 
              Write-Host "A connection to $target host cannot be made."
              Write-Host $_
              }
        }
$ssas | FL *
```

[image]